# PHPExcel: quotes in formulas when saving as xlsx (xml)

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel

We use PHPExcel v1.8.1 within a CakePHP3 application.

We create some formulas that contain quotes. Example:

```
$sheet->setCellValue($cellRef, '=SUMIF($C$2:$C$63;"abc";O2:O63)');
```

When saving as xlsx, these are written as (example):

```
<c r="O75" s="1" t="str">
    <f>
        SUMIF($C$2:$C$63;&quot;abc&quot;;O2:O63)
    </f>
    <v>0</v>
</c>
```

The quotes are transformed by the xml writer. Excel does not seem to like this. If I create an Excel spreadsheet with the formula, save the file to xlsx and view the contents of the appropriate xml file for that spreadsheet file contained within the xlsx, then it contains:

```
<c r="O75" s="1" t="str">
    <f>
        SUMIF($C$2:$C$63;"abc";O2:O63)
    </f>
    <v>0</v>
</c>
```

The xml writer would only support this if using writeRaw, if I understand it correctly. Is there a function in PHPExcel that writes cells as raw xml, or any other inbuilt way to write xml without encoding the quotes?

Comment: The `;` in your formula is invalid; you shoulld be using `,` instead.... but if you open the `/xl/worksheets/sheetX.xml` file in a text editor, you should see `&quot;` for the quote marks.... this should not cause an error, All versions of MS Excel that I've tested against read files with these quite happily

Comment: You are totally correct. And I even read about having to use commas as a separator, but was totally focused on the encoded quotes. Thanks very much!